# Question about Corollary II.5.18 in Hartshorne

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Corollary II.5.18 in Hartshorne says that if X is a projective scheme over a Noetherian ring, then any coherent sheaf on X is a quotient of a finite direct sum of twisted structure sheaves.  The statement of the result emphasizes that you might need to choose several different twists of the structure sheaf in this direct sum; however, the proof appears to show that you can choose a single twist that works.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You aren't missing anything. If a sheaf has an ample line bundle, "there are enough vector bundles", and they can be chosen to be direct sums of tensor powers of the ample line bundle.

Comment: (Further sanity checks: EGA II.2.7.10 and FAC III.2.55 state the result without the multiple twists, not sure why Hartshorne changed it...)

Comment: Of course twists of the structure sheaf are quotients of higher/larger twists.  So once you find something is a quotient of a bunch of different twists, you can use the max of the twists or larger to get a single twist that works.